# How to deploy contracts within the same Truffle project at different times

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, truffle-migration

If I have a Truffle project with two different contracts in it, can I deploy them at two separate times? Can I run an additional command alongside `truffle migrate` that will allow me to deploy just one, and then another command that will allow me to deploy the other? Is there a way to split up the migration files and just run one of them?

I am looking for best practices here.

Comment: I'm curious, what is your use case? Probably the best solution is to user your own deploying scripts.

Comment: The use case is important, here. We will almost certainly suggest a different approach but the recommendation will depend on the goal. What would be accomplished with a timed deployment?